# How to style an asp control without using a separate CSSClass?

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm a beginner in CSS and i need to set the style for all the `asp:Labels` i got in my page.
I can do this for html `label` control:

```
label
{
   color:red;
}
<label ID="mylabel" runat="server">My Text</label>
```

but that doesn't work for `asp:Label` control.

I could find online that i can do it adding a `CSSClass` attribute to each `asp:Label` control and then set the attributes of my `CSSClass` at the top of the page.

```
.myclass
{
   color:red;
}
<asp:Label ID="mylabel" runat="server" CSSClass="myclass">Test</asp:Label>
```

But this way i'll have to go through all the `asp:Label` controls and give them `CSSClass="myclass"`. Is there a way i style all my `asp:labels` in the same way i styled the html labels above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asp `label` renders like a `span` tag. So try to give style for a `span` tag.

```
label, span { color:Red; }
```

[See here for more information](http://forums.asp.net/t/1736196.aspx?Asp%20net%20Label%20renders%20as%20span)

Comment: More information: http://forums.asp.net/t/1736196.aspx?Asp+net+Label+renders+as+span

Answer (score 2):

You can use inline style sheet as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" style="color:Red;
 font: 12pt Verdana;font-weight:700;"></asp:Label>
```

You can do it from the **back end** also:

**VB:**

```
Label1.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "Red")
```

**C#:**

```
myDiv.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("color", "Red");
```